# C++ concepts for template-values and parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Was wondering what syntax would be the most effective/convenient for `concepts` on `parameters pack`, including `values template-parameters` when types (ou values' types) depend on each other?

For instance, with the following function :

> `equal_v<values...>` is true when all values are equal

```cpp
template <auto... values>
constexpr static auto equal_v = []() consteval
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(values) > 0, "equal_v : no arguments");
    constexpr auto first_value = std::get<0>(std::tuple{values...});
    static_assert(
        (std::equality_comparable_with<decltype(values), decltype(first_value)> && ...),
        "equal_v : cannot compare values");
    return ((values == first_value) && ...);
}
();
```

I would have :

```cpp
template <typename ... Ts>
concept are_equality_comparable = requires(Ts ... values)
{
    { 
        std::conditional_t<(std::equality_comparable_with<decltype(std::get<0>(std::tuple{values...})), decltype(values)> && ...), std::true_type, std::false_type>{}
    } -> std::same_as<std::true_type>;
};

template <auto ... values>
    requires(are_equality_comparable<decltype(values)...>)
constexpr static auto equal_v = []() consteval {
    static_assert(sizeof...(values) > 0, "equal_v : no arguments");
    constexpr auto first_value = std::get<0>(std::tuple{values...});
   
    return ((values == first_value) && ...); 
}();
```

Which is kinda ugly, using `std::conditional<..., std::true_type, std::false_type>` as `std::same_as<..., std::true_type>` arguments.

So I ends up with the following syntax, which I think is the most elegant :

```cpp
template <auto first_value, auto ... values>
    requires (std::equality_comparable_with<decltype(first_value), decltype(values)> && ...)
constexpr static auto equal_v = []() consteval {
    return ((values == first_value) && ...); 
}();
```

or, with not mandatory first parameter :

```cpp
template <auto ... values>
    requires (std::equality_comparable_with<decltype(std::get<0>(std::tuple{values...})), decltype(values)> && ...)
constexpr static auto equal_v = []() consteval {
    return ((values == std::get<0>(std::tuple{values...})) && ...); 
}();
```

However, as all values depends on the first one,
I did not figure out a way using such hypothetic syntax yet :

```cpp
template <auto first_value, std::equality_comparable_with<decltype(first_value)> ... values>
constexpr static auto equal_v = []() consteval {
    return ((values == first_value) && ...); 
}();
```

So, here are some points :

- Is there an elegant way to use concepts to restrict template-values's types instead of template-type-arguments?
- Is there a way to restrict types in a template-parameter-pack that depends on each other without modifying the function signature, without the `requires` clause?
  e.g `template <auto ... values>` instead of `template <auto first_value, auto ... values>`

[EDIT]
As pinpointed by [artyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5754656/artyer) in the comments, `concept auto value` is a valid syntax.
*Also, this does not work with **MSVC 19.28** as it results in :*

> error C7601: the associated constraints are not satisfied

*nor GCC 10.2 :*

> error: placeholder constraints not satisfied

*But works fine with Clang 11.0.1.*

```cpp
template <auto first_value, std::equality_comparable_with<decltype(first_value)> auto ... values> constexpr static auto equal_v = []() consteval {
   return ((values == first_value) && ...);
}();
```

[EDIT_2]

In order to make `equal_v<>` true :

```cpp
template <auto first_value = int{}, std::equality_comparable_with<decltype(first_value)> auto ... values>
constexpr static auto equal_v = []() consteval {
   return ((values == first_value) && ...);
}();
```

Comment: For the last one you are looking for `template<auto first_value, std::equalityy_comparable_with<decltype(first_value)> auto... values>` (Exactly the same as if you wanted to restrict a function parameter, you have `concept auto name`)

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks you so much.  
If I'm right, there's no mention of such syntax on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints

Comment: This works fine, but as mentioned before it use 2 templates parameters instead of 1

```cpp
template <auto first_value, std::equality_comparable_with<decltype(first_value)> auto ... values>
constexpr static auto equal_v = []() consteval {
    return ((values == first_value) && ...); 
}();
```

Comment: The `std::conditional_t` can be avoided by using a nested requirement.  You can presumably also do without the requires expression that contains it if you use `std::declval<std::tuple<Ts...>>()` (or some other pack manipulation trick.

Comment: @Artyer Do you know what is the paper that describes `concept auto value` syntax ?
Cannot find it in the original wording [p0734r0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0734r0.pdf)

Comment: As an aside, `equal_v<>` not being trivially `true`, but instead an error, is quite unexpected.

Comment: @Guss: It’s [P1141](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p1141r2.html), although some vaguely similar syntaxes were *removed* from versions of the original proposal prior to P0734.

Comment: @DavisHerring : Thank you ! After few syntaxes attempt, it looks like the issue is not related to concept-restricted values but constant-expression.  
For instance, this works on Clang but not GCC and MsVC https://godbolt.org/z/4E7o9n
Also, according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support, Clang and GCC totaly implements https://wg21.link/P1141R2.

Comment: @Deduplicator : Totally agree, that is the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as conclusion, here are answers to the two questions :

- **How to apply constraints on template-value-parameters ?**

  As pin-pointed by @**Artyer** and @**Davis Herring**, `concept auto value` is a legal syntax defined in [p1141r2](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p1141r2.html).
  **NB** : It's not currently part of **cppreference** documentation.
- **How to apply constraints on parameters-packs, when types depend on each-others ?**

  - Using constrained-auto *(`concept (auto) arg` syntax)* :

    Defining the first one with a default value *(to preserve parameterless resolutions)*,
    and applying the contraints on a parameter-pack that contain parameters which remain.

    ```cpp
    template <auto first_value = int{}, 
                  std::equality_comparable_with<decltype(first_value)> auto ... values>
        constexpr static auto equal_v = []() consteval {
           return ((values == first_value) && ...);
        }();
    ```
  - Using `requires`-clause syntax :

    ```cpp
    template <auto ... values>
      requires (std::equality_comparable_with<
         decltype(std::get<0>(std::tuple{values...})),
         decltype(values)
      > && ...)
    constexpr static auto equal_v = []() consteval {
    return ((values == std::get<0>(std::tuple{values...})) && ...); 
    }();
    ```